# Change multiple party choices variables into one yes no variables for all my sample

Tags: r, character, data-cleaning, recode, vote

I am studying the votes in home and host country elections looking at the turkish diaspora in Europe.

Since I already have a yes-no variable (meaning did you vote or not) for the home country election, I'd like to have the same for all host countries of my dataset.

As it is I have the following variables each for one country coded "partyname" or "none" or NA. Example for Germany D$partyvotedger its either "SPD", "none" or NA. They are character vectors.

```
1 NA                                     
 2 SPD                                    
 3 none / not chosen / not going to choose
 4 NA                                     
 5 none / not chosen / not going to choose
 6 none / not chosen / not going to choose
 7 none / not chosen / not going to choose
 8 NA                                     
 9 none / not chosen / not going to choose
10 none / not chosen / not going to choose
# … with 2,347 more rows
#
```

I'd like to combine all four countries into one variable coded "yes" "no" or NA where "yes" occurs whenever a party name appears and no whenever "none" appears.

Get something like this: (This the vote in home country election where 0= no and 1= yes)

```
`D$vote_turkey`
             <dbl>
 1               0
 2               0
 3               1
 4               1
 5               1
 6               1
 7               1
 8               0
 9               0
10               1
```

Has anyone here an Idea of what function or code structure I should use ? Do I need to first create a yes-no for each country before having a unique one ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

All the best.

Comment: Would you like `NA` to remain `NA`, or to be coded as a no?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. Actually in each voting variables NA are either real missing values or rows applying to other countries in the dataset hence, i'd like them to remain NA.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.
First I create an example data set based on what you have provided.

```
library(dplyr)

#creating the example data frame
example <- data.frame("partyvotedgr" = c(NA,                                     
                                           "SPD",                               
                                           "none / not chosen / not going to choose",
                                           NA,
                                           "none / not chosen / not going to choose",
                                           "none / not chosen / not going to choose",
                                           "none / not chosen / not going to choose",
                                           NA,
                                           "none / not chosen / not going to choose",
                                           "none / not chosen / not going to choose",
                                           "CDU",
                                           "DIE LINKE"))
#checking how the table looks like
example
"partyvotedgr
1                                     <NA>
2                                      SPD
3  none / not chosen / not going to choose
4                                     <NA>
5  none / not chosen / not going to choose
6  none / not chosen / not going to choose
7  none / not chosen / not going to choose
8                                     <NA>
9  none / not chosen / not going to choose
10 none / not chosen / not going to choose
11                                     CDU
12                               DIE LINKE"
```

I noticed that you're currently focusing on Germany so I added some additional political parties for better simulation.

Then, you declare a string vector that contains a list of parties in a target company. For instance, it would be like this for Germany.

```
#retrieving only 2 & 3
party_value <- c("SPD", "CDU", "DIE LINKE")
```

Of course you should add more values to cover all the parties.

Then you create a similar column(`vote_ger`) like the `vote_turkey`. I give the NA value as a base value.

```
#creating the 'vote_ger' column
example <- example %>% 
  mutate(vote_ger = NA_character_)
```

Next, you change the `vote_ger` values according to the values in the `partyvotedgr` values.

```
#adjusting the vote_ger values
#creating the yes values according to the party_value
example <- example %>%
  mutate(vote_ger=ifelse(partyvotedgr %in% party_value,
                         "yes",
                         vote_ger))
```

Please note that `%in%` operator is a set operation returning boolean values(either True or False). In this case, it is returning if an element in the `partyvotedgr` column is an element of the `party_value` vector.

You do almost the exact same process to give `"no"` values in the `vote_ger` column.

```
#creating the no values if they have the value 'none / not chosen / not going to choose' in the partyvotedgr column
example <- example %>%
  mutate(vote_ger=ifelse(partyvotedgr %in% "none / not chosen / not going to choose",
                         "no",
                         vote_ger))
```

This time, `vote_ger` column will have a `"no"` if it has `"none / not chosen / not going to choose"` value in the `partyvotedgr` column.

After all the process the data set `example` looks like this.

```
#the result
example

"partyvotedgr vote_ger
1                                     <NA>     <NA>
2                                      SPD      yes
3  none / not chosen / not going to choose       no
4                                     <NA>     <NA>
5  none / not chosen / not going to choose       no
6  none / not chosen / not going to choose       no
7  none / not chosen / not going to choose       no
8                                     <NA>     <NA>
9  none / not chosen / not going to choose       no
10 none / not chosen / not going to choose       no
11                                     CDU      yes
12                               DIE LINKE      yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple in base-r because R vectorises comparison operators for you.

If the "no" value is always the same string, then `!=` will be enough:

```
example$vote <- as.numeric(example$partyvotedgr != "none / not chosen / not going to choose")

example
                              partyvotedgr vote
1                                     <NA>   NA
2                                      SPD    1
3  none / not chosen / not going to choose    0
4                                     <NA>   NA
5  none / not chosen / not going to choose    0
6  none / not chosen / not going to choose    0
7  none / not chosen / not going to choose    0
8                                     <NA>   NA
9  none / not chosen / not going to choose    0
10 none / not chosen / not going to choose    0
11                                     CDU    1
12                               DIE LINKE    1
```

The `!=` comparison returns an array of TRUE, FALSE and NA, and `as.numeric` turns the TRUE/FALSE into 1/0. Consider whether it may be better to keep them as TRUE/FALSE.

If there are several options that count as "no", the operator would be `%in%`, as in `(!example$partyvotedgr %in% c("none", "not chosen", "not going to choose"))`

Thank you to B_Heidel for the example df.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, very usefull and pedgogically written !